How to display full process name in pm2 list?
I am using pm2 to run my processes in background, and I created it with quite a long process name.
Whenever I execute pm2 list, I only see a small part of the process name.

How can I display the process name in full from the command pm2 list?
I tried pm2 list --help but there is no option to choose.

you can try following command:
pm2 describe id


It displays the full process name, yes, along with many other data. It eats up a whole chunk of display. I just want to see the full process name in the pm2 list result. That's all.

if your script as a very long name, you can provide you on name when you create the task:
pm2 create --name "My shorty task name" /path/to/my/very-very-long-task-name

In case your script is already running, you can change his name with
pm2 restart <task ID> --name "My shorty task name"


I named them that way. It is actually not that long though. I just want to see the full name. I don't want to shorten them.

Ok, that's because your terminal window is too small in width, try to expand it horizontally. Currently your screenshot show that your in condensed mode.
